# Shorter order expression in R

Tags: r

I seem to do this a lot

`table(citylist$country)[order(table(citylist$country))]`

is there a shorter way to get the same result without repeating the command inside of the order() function?

example:

```
df<-airquality
table(df$Temp)
table(df$Temp)[order(table(df$Temp))]
```

Comment: If you're repeating the same command many times, you should put it in a function, and then call the function many times instead. Then it won't matter how torturous the code is, because you only have to write it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is:

```
identical(sort(table(df$Temp)), table(df$Temp)[order(table(df$Temp))])
# [1] TRUE
```

Just like for any other (possibly named, as is the case with `table`) vector `x`:

```
x <- rnorm(10)
identical(sort(x), x[order(x)])
# [1] TRUE
```